# Change SwiftUI Text from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm quite new to Swift and absolute new to SwiftUI.
I'm trying to combine `UIViewController` Google Maps and modern SwiftUI.
In SwiftUI i have a few `Text` objects, and I want my `GmapsController` class to be able to modify these Text values, and redraw SwiftUI struct.

My main struct:

```
var _swiftUIStruct : swiftUIStruct = swiftUIStruct() // to have access in GmapsController
struct GoogMapView: View {
    var body: some View {
        let gmap = GmapsControllerRepresentable()
        return  ZStack {
            gmap
            _swiftUIStruct
        }
    }
}
```

`UIViewControllerRepresentable` wrapper of `GmapsController` :

```
struct GmapsControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<GmapsControllerRepresentable>) -> GmapsController {
        return GmapsController()
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GmapsController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<GmapsControllerRepresentable>) {}
}
```

The `GmapsController` itself:

```
class GmapsController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    var mapView: GMSMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self

        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(
            withLatitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!,
            longitude: (locationManager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!,
            zoom: 15
        )

        mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: view.bounds, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView
    }

// HERE I WANT TO CHANGE SOME swiftUIStruct Text FIELDS

// calls after map move
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt сameraPosition: GMSCameraPosition) {
        _swiftUIStruct.someTxt = "I hope this will work" // compilation pass, but value doesn't change
    }
}
```

And the swiftUIStruct struct:

```
struct swiftUIStruct {
    @State var someTxt = ""
    var body: some View {
        Text(someTxt) // THE TEXT I WISH I COULD CHANGE
    }
}
```

Googling this a whole day just made me feel dumb, any help is appreciated.

Comment: @KevinRenskers Thanks for the answer! I was playing around with ```@Binding```, but got no luck there. I'm pretty sure I've done something wrong, and a little code will help me.

Comment: I am seeing multiple issues with your code, this is never going to work like this. Let me write up some example code to give you a better idea on how to make this all work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope my example code helps. Basically, move the model data outside, and pass it along, and change it. If you run this code, you will see the text "I hope this will work", NOT "Initial Content".

```swift
import SwiftUI

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var someTxt = "Initial Content"
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @ObservedObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      GoogleMapsView(viewModel: viewModel)
      Text(viewModel.someTxt)
    }
  }
}

struct GoogleMapsView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
  var viewModel: ViewModel

  func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> GmapsController {
    let controller = GmapsController()
    controller.viewModel = viewModel
    return controller
  }
  func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: GmapsController, context: Context) {}
}

class GmapsController: UIViewController {
  var viewModel: ViewModel?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    viewModel?.someTxt = "I hope this will work"
  }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    return ContentView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try tomorrow! Let you know, if that worked for me! Have a nice day (night)!

Comment: seems like we can think of the `ViewModel` with Publisher var as the delegate pattern... coming from a UIKit world...